# Crash using concurrent_unordered_map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I've got a `concurrent_unordered_map`. I use the `insert` function (and no other) to try to insert into the map concurrently. However, many times, this crashes deep in the `insert` function internals. Here is some code:

```
class ModuleBase { 
public:
    virtual Wide::Parser::AST* GetAST() = 0;
    virtual ~ModuleBase() {} 
};
struct ModuleContents {
    ModuleContents() {}
    ModuleContents(ModuleContents&& other)
        : access(other.access)
        , base(std::move(other.base)) {}
    Accessibility access;
    std::unique_ptr<ModuleBase> base;
};
class Module : public ModuleBase {
public:
    // Follows Single Static Assignment form. Once it's been written, do not write again. 
    Concurrency::samples::concurrent_unordered_map<Unicode::String, ModuleContents> contents;
    Wide::Parser::AST* GetAST() { return AST; }
    Wide::Parser::NamespaceAST* AST;
};
```

This is the function I use to actually insert into the map. There is more but it doesn't touch the map, only uses the return value of `insert`.

```
void CollateModule(Parser::NamespaceAST* module, Module& root, Accessibility access_level) {
// Build the new module, then try to insert it. If it comes back as existing, then we discard. Else, it was inserted and we can process.
Module* new_module = nullptr;
ModuleContents m;
{
    if (module->dynamic) {
        auto dyn_mod = MakeUnique<DynamicModule>();
        dyn_mod->libname = module->libname->contents;
        new_module = dyn_mod.get();
        m.base = std::move(dyn_mod);     
    } else {
        auto mod = MakeUnique<Module>();
        new_module = mod.get();
        m.base = std::move(mod);
    }
    new_module->AST = module;
    m.access = access_level;
}
auto result = root.contents.insert(std::make_pair(module->name->name, std::move(m)));
```

This is the root function. It is called in parallel from many threads on different inputs, but with the same `root`.

```
void Collater::Context::operator()(Wide::Parser::NamespaceAST* input, Module& root) {
std::for_each(input->contents.begin(), input->contents.end(), [&](Wide::Parser::AST* ptr) {
    if (auto mod_ptr = dynamic_cast<Wide::Parser::NamespaceAST*>(ptr)) {
        CollateModule(mod_ptr, root, Accessibility::Public);
    }
});
}
```

I'm not entirely sure wtf is going on. I've got one bit of shared state, and I only ever access it atomically, so why is my code dying?

Edit: This is actually completely my own fault. The crash was in the `insert` line, which I assumed to be the problem- but it *wasn't*. It wasn't related to the concurrency at all. I tested the return value of `result` the *wrong way around*- i.e., `true` for `value existed`, `false` for `value did not exist`, whereas the Standard defines `true` for `insertion succeeded`- i.e., `value did not exist`. This mucked up the memory management significantly, causing a crash- although exactly how it led to a crash in the `unordered_map` code, I don't know. Once I inserted the correct negation, it worked flawlessly. This was revealed because I didn't properly test the single-threaded version before jumping the concurrent fence.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you are crashing because of some problem with move semantics. Is the crash caused by a null pointer dereference? That would happen if you inadvertently accessed an object (e.g., `ModuleContents`) after it's been moved.

It's also possible that the crash is the result of a concurrency bug. The `concurrent_unordered_map` is thread safe in the sense that insertion and retrieval are atomic. However, whatever you are storing inside it is not automatically protected. So if multiple threads retrieve the same `ModuleContents` object, they will share the AST tree that's inside a `Module`. I'm not sure which references are modifiable, since I don't see any `const` pointers or references. Anything that is shared and modifiable must be protected by some synchronization mechanism (for instance, locks).

Comment: Your point about lack of const-correctness is a good one. However, only the `concurrent_unordered_map` is actually *mutable*.

Comment: Why don't you add all the const qualifiers you believe are true and see if it compiles. Also, make sure you don't have any mutable references to those const objects.

Comment: I did just that to actually verify my assumption, and it was valid. However, I did discover the actual problem. See my edit for the solution.